# Dense cyclic subgroup

Tags: topological-groups

Does anyone know a continuous group (not necessarily locally compact) with dense cyclic subgroup other than a torus?

Comment: Anything procyclic. Someone below already listed the $p$-adic integers, although I'm not sure why this example wasn't one in which you're interested. Another is the absolute Galois group of a finite field of size $q$, which is topologically generated ($=$ equal to the closure of the abstract subgroup generated) by the Frobenius automorphism $x\mapsto x^q$. This is just $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$, the product over all primes $p$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: Take your favorite group, and give it the indiscrete topology.  Then the identity element comprises a dense cyclic subgroup.  Presumably you don't want this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have some examples in the other answers. Groups which have a dense cyclic subgroup are called *Monothetic* groups. In the article "On monothetic groups" by P.R. Halmos and H. Samelson, you can find many of their properties, such as

> Every compact connected separable (abelian) group is monothetic.

Answer (score 4):

First, it is clear the group has to be abelian. Now, if you assume that $G$ is locally compact, then by the classification you can decompose $G$ as $G={\mathbb R}^n \times H$ where
$H$ has a compact open subgroup. Clearly, there can be no ${\mathbb R}^n$ factor, so $G$ has a
compact open subgroup. Now, suppose $G$ is itself compact and topologically generated by $g$. Then any character $\chi$ in the dual of $G$ vanishing on $g$ will be identically zero. So, the map
$\chi \mapsto \chi (g)$ is injective, hence the dual is a subgroup of $U(1)$.  Conversely, you can also see that if $\Gamma$ is a subgroup of $U(1)$ (considered with the discrete topology) then the dual of $\Gamma$ has a dense cyclic subgroup. By taking various subgroups you can, for instance, get the $p$-adic integers, or the n-torus.

Answer (score 1):

How about the Bohr compactification of the infinite cyclic group?

Answer (score 0):

How about the infinite cyclic group itself with the discrete topology? Or p-adic integers?

Comment: I care about is not a question of existence obvious examples like this. In some sense and for some reasons p-adic integers for me are not much better than infinite dimensional torus (IDT). It is easy to understand, that forgetting about topology, p-adic integers realized subgroup of IDT. Need something unlike torus. Sorry for my english.